# Problem on strncpy with source string longer than destination array

Tags: c, buffer, c-strings, strncpy

I tried to think how to make the function `strncpy` and I met this problem.

```
    char src[] = "123456789A";
    char dest[10];
    int n = 10;
    printf("strncpy:%s\n", strncpy(dest, src, n));
```

**Output**

```
strncpy:123456789A123456789A
```

What is happening ?

Comment: `dest` does not have space for the terminating null character so it will not have in the end, therefore printf will keep printing from memory until it not find a null char.

Comment: meet undefined behaviour

Comment: Read carefully the documentation of `strncpy` especially what happens when the string is larger than the maximal size specified. Basically the `strncpy` function is useless. There are not many use cases where the usage of `strncpy` makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick answer: `strncpy` **is not your friend!**

`strncpy` is **not** a *safer* version of `strcpy`, it will copy up to `n` characters from `src` and if `src` is shorter, will pad the destination with null bytes up a total of `n` characters.

If the source string has `n` or more characters, the destination array will **not be null terminated** and passing to `printf("%s",` will have **undefined behavior**: `printf` will keep reading and printing bytes from memory after the end of `dest`, until it finds a null byte or until this undefined behavior causes other unpredictable side effects...

The semantics of `strncpy` are counter-intuitive and error-prone, avoid usng this function. See this article for a long answer: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/

Answer (score 1):

The array `dest` does not contain a string because there is no enough space to accommodate the terminating zero `'\0'` of the copied source string,

So to output the array use the following statement

```
printf("strncpy: %*.*s\n", n, n, strncpy(dest, src, n));
```

Otherwise you have to write something like the following

```
strncpy( dest, src, n )[sizeof( dest ) - 1] = '\0';

printf("strncpy: %s\n", dest );
```

In this case the destination array will not have the last character of the source string that will be overwritten by the zero character.

If you want to copy less characters than the size of the destination array then what to do after copying depends on the intention. If you want just to overwrite part of the string that is already stored in the destination array then nothing else you need to do. Otherwise set the character at position `n` to zero character.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char src[] = "123456789A";
    char dest[10] = "543216789";

    size_t n = 5;

    strncpy( dest, src, n );

    printf("strncpy: %s\n", dest );

    strncpy( dest, "Hello", n )[n] = '\0';

    printf("strncpy: %s\n", dest );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
strncpy: 123456789
strncpy: Hello
```

Comment: @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes It does not matter.

Comment: @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes There is neither undefined behavior. There is used the size of the destination array in the call of strncpy.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said `strncpy` won't include a terminating null if the destination size is the same as the string length. To give you a practical answer I normally just subtract one from the size of the destination using `sizeof` to get the destination size including space for the terminator:

```
char src[] = "123456789A";
char dest[10];
printf("strncpy:%s\n", strncpy(dest, src, sizeof(dest) - 1));
```

Which gives an  output of "strncpy:123456789" which is a character short of what you want but at least is defined behaviour and lets you know the destination buffer isn't large enough to contain the null terminator. So the final code that gives you the result you're after would be:

```
char src[] = "123456789A";
char dest[11];
printf("strncpy:%s\n", strncpy(dest, src, sizeof(dest) - 1));
```

Comment: `printf("strncpy:%s\n", strncpy(dest, src, sizeof(dest) - 1));` has undefined behavior in both cases because `dest[sizeof(dest)-1]` stays uninitialized.